# How can I use different authentication methods for different MQTT endpoints? [Mosquitto]

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto MQTT Broker, configured for Websockets on one port, and mqtt over another.

I have a custom authentication plugin, and it works well. What I want, however, is that only clients connecting over websockets use my plugin, and clients connecting over mqtt protocol use the default TLS authentication.

I am hoping there is some simple setting I have overlooked that I can add to the configuration file, but any/all solutions are welcome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mosquitto.conf [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

> **per_listener_settings [ true | false ]**
>
> If true, then authentication and access control settings will be controlled on a per-listener basis. The following options are
> affected:
>
> ```
> password_file, acl_file, psk_file, allow_anonymous, allow_zero_length_clientid, auth_plugin, auth_opt_*, auto_id_prefix.
> ```
>
> Note that if set to true, then a durable client (i.e. with clean session set to false) that has disconnected will use the ACL settings
> defined for the listener that it was most recently connected to.
>
> The default behaviour is for this to be set to false, which maintains the settings behaviour from previous versions of mosquitto.
>
> Reloaded on reload signal.

If you set this to true then you can include listerner specific settings under each `listener` entry in the config file and they will each have their own acl/user settings.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I am not sure how I missed this before, thanks!